# How can i build a WCF+MySQL Server which can communicate with differents clients(differents OS)?

Tags: mysql, wcf

I want to build a WCF Server with MySQL Database which can communicate with differents Clients on differents OS. Is that Possible?

if Yes, how should i go? any tutorials which can help me?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that Possible?

Yes, interoperability was one of the main concerns of the WCF designers.

> how should i go?

There are so many options you need to consider, for example security, reliability...
But mainly basicHttpBinding is probably **the most interoperable *SOAP-based* binding**. Just google for samples of `basicHttpBinding`.

On another account, **the most interoperable WCF approach** is `WCF REST` which can allow use of JSON that any client can understand, even the browser. However, implementation of WCF REST has quite a few design problems (outside scope of this question) and I would suggest using ASP NET MVC to implement passing JSON objects over HTTP. For security, you can use HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks Aliostad!! but i want to use it into a LAN Environment. So i will build first of all WPF applications Clients. is this Option possible too?

Comment: Yes, intranet or internet does not matter. WPF or Silverlight or Windows forms, you can use WCF client to connect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Answer!! i will do it this way : 1. Configure a LAN; 2. on the Server PC an Apache Server with Mysql; 3. On clients PC WPF applications with WCF REST to communicate with the Database. it's ok isn't?